# Help making my root directory not executable for CGI scripts

Tags: apache-2.2, cgi

I'm trying to make the root directory for a virtual host so that it can execute CGI scripts. I put the following in my virtual host declaration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory />
    Options +ExecCGI
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot /path/to/root
    ServerName servername
    AddHandler cgi-script .pl
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you're wanting to allow cgi scripts to run in the root directory you're going to want to change the Directory section. I think you're confusing Directory with Location. Directory refers to a directory on disk whereas Location refers to a path from the document root.

So what you want is something more like:

```
<Directory /path/to/root>
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

See [Apache Tutorial: Dynamic Content with CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html) for more info.

Comment: And generally the default apache conf already has "Directory /" defined with most options turned off for security.  So perhaps the "Directory /" you (blockhead) defined is conflicting with that one.  This solution from Hans should work.